# Is there a way of evaluating the limit of this sum?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $T$ be some real positive constant and let $\pi:=\{0=t_0<t_1<\cdots<t_N=T\}$ be an uniform partition of the interval $[0,T]$ where by "uniform" I mean that $t_j=jT/N$ for $j\in\{0,1,...,N\}$.

I was wondering if it's possible to make sense of this limit for any $t\in [0,T]$

$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} \mathbf{1}_{[t_j,t_{j+1})}(t)\left(\frac{t-t_j}{t_{j+1}-t_j}\right).$$

I would expect this to converge in some sense to $1/2$ since as the partition becomes finer then $t$ would be closer and closer to the middle point of the interval, but this is just a conjecture.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit doesn't exist.

Consider $t\in[0,T]$ and let $k\in {0,1,...,N-1}$ be such that $t\in[t_k,t_{k+1})$ then

$$
\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}{\bf{1}}_{[t_j,t_{j+1})}\left(\frac{t-t_j}{t_{j+1}-t_j}\right)=\frac{(t-kT/N)}{T/N}=N(t/T)-k
$$

Now as $t\in[t_k,t_{k+1})=[kT/N,(k+1)T/N)$, $N(t/T)\in[k,k+1)$ and $k=\lfloor N(t/T)\rfloor$. Then

$$
\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}{\bf{1}}_{[t_j,t_{j+1})}\left(\frac{t-t_j}{t_{j+1}-t_j}\right)=N(t/T)-\lfloor N(t/T)\rfloor
$$

And this does not converge. For instance if $t/T=1/2$ Then $N(t/T)-\lfloor N(t/T)\rfloor$ is equal to $1/2$ if $N$ is odd and $0$ if N is even. (In fact it doesn't converge for any $t/T\in (0,1)$).